# Highcharts how to only plot if x axis is having value greater than 0?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

Guys I have a simple high-chart graph which is displaying number of issues and number of issues resolved per day basis. The start date of the graph is -30 days from current date. So it will always display data per 30 days.

Now what I want to do is dynamically start the chart from where the data on x-axis is greater than 0.

For example if issue/resolve count of 29 days is 0 and on 30th day the issue count is raised to 1, I want to start the graph from 30th day and so on.

This is the code for my chart

```
$('#performance-cart').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'area', backgroundColor: '#f5f7f7', style: { fontFamily: 'Roboto, Sans-serif', color: '#aeafb1' },
        animation: {
            duration: 1500,
            easing: 'easeOutBounce'
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        labels: { style: { color: '#aeafb1' } }
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0, max: maxVal, tickInterval: 10, gridLineColor: '#ebeded', gridLineWidth: 1,
        title: { text: '' }, lineWidth: 0, labels: { align: 'right', style: { color: '#aeafb1' } }
    },
    title: { text: '' },
    tooltip: {
        useHTML: true, headerFormat: '<h3 style="color:#ffffff;font-weight:300;padding: 3px 12px;">{point.y:,.1f}</br>',
        backgroundColor: '#515757', pointFormat: 'Issues</h3>'//$('#performanceColumnChart').data('tooltip')
    },
    legend: {
        itemStyle: { color: '#838589' }, symbolWidth: 12, symbolHeight: 5, itemWidth: 80, symbolRadius: 0,
        itemMarginBottom: 10, backgroundColor: '#f5f7f7', verticalAlign: 'top', borderWidth: 0, x: -498, y: 10
    },
    plotOptions: {
        area: {
            fillOpacity: 0.2, cursor: 'pointer', marker: {
                symbol: 'circle', fillColor: '#FFFFFF', lineWidth: 2, lineColor: null,
                allowPointSelect: true
            }
        },
        line: {
            fillOpacity: 0.2, cursor: 'pointer', marker: {
                symbol: 'circle', fillColor: '#FFFFFF', lineWidth: 2, lineColor: null,
                allowPointSelect: true
            }
        },
        column: {
            fillOpacity: 0.2, cursor: 'pointer', marker: {
                symbol: 'circle', fillColor: '#FFFFFF', lineWidth: 2, lineColor: null,
                allowPointSelect: true
            }
        },
        series: {
            pointStart: myDateVariable,
            pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 // one day
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Issues', color: '#ff3806',
        data: myIssueData,
        marker: { states: { hover: { fillColor: '#ff3806', lineColor: '#ffffff', lineWidth: 2 } } }
    }, {
        name: 'Resolved', color: '#1da9dd',
        data: myResolvedData,
        marker: { states: { hover: { fillColor: '#1da9dd', lineColor: '#ffffff', lineWidth: 2 } } }
    }]
});
```

Is this approach even possible ? if so, I would like some pointers. I have searched the high-charts official documentation but was unable to get any help from that.

Comment: You can adapt your data in the preprocessing, in other words before add it to the highcharts, parse it and get rid of incorrect points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way would be to pre-process your data such that `myIssueData` meets your requirements. You have not stated what you use to generate your data so the answer to that would depend on your data source. For SQL-based you can query for the most recent non-0 issue date and then use that date as the start point of your query. Psuedo-code:

```
DECLARE @startDate AS datetime

SELECT @startDate = MAX(date)
FROM myIssuesTable
WHERE issueCountColumn > 0

SELECT date, issueCountColumn
FROM myIssuesTable
WHERE date >= @startDate
ORDER BY date ASC
```

The result of the second query becomes your `myIssueData`. This does not account for cases where the issue count has been above 0 for more than thirty days but you can just skip this query in this case and use a direct query for `date` 30 days ago from today.

Comment: This could work too but my approach was a little different. I did all of this on client side by removing the leading zeros from array of data that is being plotted on x-axis.